# How do I count the number of digits of several numbers and then format them in tabular form?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a very simple program that I'm writing for class that calculates revenue based on a fixed ticket price. After multiplying it by a number of tickets provided by the user, formats it first with a comma in the thousands places, and then adds a dollar sign in front of it, and finally returns it as a string to be listed in a column with a fixed title at the top.

What I want to know is if there is a way to first count the number of digits in the string produced at the end (including the dollar sign and comma) and adjust the width of the column based on that if the number of spaces is longer than the minimum number of spaces to properly display the header of the column, if this makes sense.

Just as an FYI, the script already outputs the results as required for the project, I'm just trying to take it a little further to expand my own understanding. Also, I know this might not all be the best way to structure this program, so any advice would be welcome:

```
# Define ticket prices

SILVER_TIC_PRICE = 35
GOLD_TIC_PRICE = 55
PLATINUM_TIC_PRICE = 85

# Create Functions

# Validate tickets sold as an interger

def tickets_sold(message):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('\nERROR : \nInvalid entry \nPlease use a number\n')
            continue
        try:
            assert user_input >= 0
        except AssertionError:
            print('\nERROR : \nInvalid entry \nPlease use a positive number\n')
            continue
        else:
            return user_input
            break

# Reusable line function

def print_line(ticket_class, tickets_sold, ticket_revenue):
    print(format(ticket_class, " >8"), format(tickets_sold, " >7"), format(ticket_revenue, " <7"), sep='  ')

# Format Function

# def format_final()

# Get the number of tickets sold by type
# But first a blank line for readability

print(' ')

# Get Silver tickets sold

silver_tickets_sold = tickets_sold ('Enter the number of Silver tickets sold: ')

# Get Gold tickets sold

gold_ticket_sold = tickets_sold('Enter the number of Gold tickets sold: ')

# Get Platinum tickets sold

platinum_ticket_sold = tickets_sold('Enter the number of Platinum tickets sold: ')

# calculate revenue

silver_initial = int(silver_tickets_sold * SILVER_TIC_PRICE)
gold_initial = int(gold_ticket_sold * GOLD_TIC_PRICE)
platinum_initial = int(platinum_ticket_sold * PLATINUM_TIC_PRICE)

silver_final = "{:,}".format(silver_initial)
gold_final = "{:,}".format(gold_initial)
platinum_final = "{:,}".format(platinum_initial)

silver_revenue = '$' + str(silver_final)
gold_revenue = '$' + str(gold_final)
platinum_revenue = '$' + str(platinum_final)

# calculate totals

total_tickets = int(silver_tickets_sold + gold_ticket_sold + platinum_ticket_sold)
total_initial = int(silver_initial + gold_initial + platinum_initial)

total_final = "{:,}".format(total_initial)

total_revenue = '$'+str(total_final)

# display results

print(' ')
print_line('Section','Tickets','Revenue')
print_line('--------','-------','-------')
print_line('Silver', silver_tickets_sold, silver_revenue)
print_line('Gold', gold_ticket_sold,gold_revenue)
print_line('Platinum', platinum_ticket_sold, platinum_revenue)
print_line('========','=======','=======')
print_line('Total', total_tickets, total_revenue)
print(' ')
```

I know there are already questions that answer parts of this, but I couldn't find anything that combines the parts in a way I have been able to wrap my brain around.

Comment: Use some table-package that already does that for you (in increasing order of dependency complexity) `tabulate`, `pandas`, `astropy.table` come to mind.

Comment: Also please include the current behavior and the *desired* behavior so that we know what's actually the problem you're trying to solve here :)

Comment: currently I can only format the length of the field to a fixed amount (in the reusable line function), what I'd like it to do is count the numbers in each of the outputs, and if they are longer than the minimum number required to properly display the header, adjust the length of the format to be the longest. I.e. if the result of the number of tickets sold multiplied by the cost results in a string longer than 8 characters, adjust the format to that number, if none of them are, leave the it at the number required to display the column headers. does that help?

Comment: and second apologies, but we aren't supposed to use any packages yet in these scripts...

Comment: @richwoo math is part of the standard library, are you allowed to use that?

Comment: If it helps illustrate how basic we were supposed to write it, I caught a little bit of grief showing this to my professor for using except to catch the errors. I have some experience doing the "script-kiddie" thing, which is why I "over wrote" it in the first place, but even creating the functions in there was another point I got the proverbial 'raised eyebrow' over... so while I might have to redo the whole thing using just if/then and while (and a lot of repetition) I'm taking everything I was shown here and stashing it in my pocket for further along in the course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let me start with a bit of code-review:

The first function is quite good. It correctly uses `while True` and `break` until a valid number is given. However there is some room for improvement:

```
def tickets_sold(message):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('\nERROR : \nInvalid entry \nPlease use a number\n')
            continue
        if user_input < 0:   # better to use an if instead of "try: assert"
            print('\nERROR : \nInvalid entry \nPlease use a positive number\n')
            continue
        return user_input  # just return all other cases already "continue"d
```

However then it starts with a lot of repetition, I would put the code that asks for the tickets and then returns the number of tickets and the revenue. By putting some of it into functions a lot (not all) of the repetition can be simply avoided:

```
def get_tickets_and_revenue(name, tic_price):
    n_tickets_sold = tickets_sold('Enter the number of {} tickets sold: '.format(name))
    revenue = int(n_tickets_sold * tic_price)
    return n_tickets_sold, revenue


silver_tickets_sold, silver_revenue = get_tickets_and_revenue('Silver', SILVER_TIC_PRICE)
gold_ticket_sold, gold_revenue = get_tickets_and_revenue('Gold', GOLD_TIC_PRICE)
platinum_ticket_sold, platinum_revenue = get_tickets_and_revenue('Platinum', PLATINUM_TIC_PRICE)

total_tickets = silver_tickets_sold + gold_ticket_sold + platinum_ticket_sold
total_revenue = silver_revenue + gold_revenue + platinum_revenue

def format_number_according_to_spec(num):
    return '${:,}'.format(num)

# only now convert them to strings!
silver_revenue = format_number_according_to_spec(silver_revenue)
gold_revenue = format_number_according_to_spec(gold_revenue)
platinum_revenue = format_number_according_to_spec(platinum_revenue)
total_revenue = format_number_according_to_spec(total_revenue)
```

The next part could probably be shortened by keeping the values as iterables but it also works with hardcoding:

```
def find_column_length(*column_values):
    # using "len(str(sth))" you can determine the length!
    return max(len(str(value)) for value in column_values)

# The row formatter is formatted twice, once with the length values and once
# with the actual values. So we need to escape the outer {} by doubling them.
row_formatter = '{{:>{}}}  {{:>{}}}  {{:>{}}}'
column_lengths = [find_column_length('Section', 
                                     'Silver', 
                                     'Gold', 
                                     'Platinum', 
                                     'Total'),
                  find_column_length('Tickets', 
                                     silver_tickets_sold, 
                                     gold_ticket_sold, 
                                     platinum_ticket_sold, 
                                     total_tickets),
                  find_column_length('Revenue', 
                                     silver_revenue, 
                                     gold_revenue, 
                                     platinum_revenue, 
                                     total_revenue)]
row_formatter = row_formatter.format(*column_lengths)
placeholder1 = '{}  {}  {}'.format('-'*column_lengths[0],
                                   '-'*column_lengths[1],
                                   '-'*column_lengths[2])
placeholder2 = '{}  {}  {}'.format('='*column_lengths[0],
                                   '='*column_lengths[1],
                                   '='*column_lengths[2])

print(' ')
print(row_formatter.format('Section','Tickets','Revenue'))
print(placeholder1)
print(row_formatter.format('Silver', silver_tickets_sold, silver_revenue))
print(row_formatter.format('Gold', gold_ticket_sold,gold_revenue))
print(row_formatter.format('Platinum', platinum_ticket_sold, platinum_revenue))
print(placeholder2)
print(row_formatter.format('Total', total_tickets, total_revenue))
print(' ')
```

For example:

```
Enter the number of Silver tickets sold: 200000000
Enter the number of Gold tickets sold: 1
Enter the number of Platinum tickets sold: 20

 Section    Tickets         Revenue
--------  ---------  --------------
  Silver  200000000  $7,000,000,000
    Gold          1             $55
Platinum         20          $1,700
========  =========  ==============
   Total  200000021  $7,000,001,755
```

and

```
Enter the number of Silver tickets sold: 2
Enter the number of Gold tickets sold: 5
Enter the number of Platinum tickets sold: 1

 Section  Tickets  Revenue
--------  -------  -------
  Silver        2      $70
    Gold        5     $275
Platinum        1      $85
========  =======  =======
   Total        8     $430
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number and you are only interested in the magnitude and it is base ten then.

```
import math
math.ceil(math.log(n,10))
```

should work.
or you could use either of:

```
len(str(n))

len(str(n).replace(".",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a small code that will give you the count of number of numbers in the final string total_revenue.

```
# Initialize the counter
count_number = 0

# Get the count of numbers
for c in total_revenue:
    if(c.isdigit()):
        count_number += 1

# Display the count
print(count_number)
```